# Swift Type does not conform to protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

The error occurs on the class `VendingMachine: VendingMachineType{}`

I can't seem to find the discrepancy that is causing the problem. Did I miss something or am I looking in the wrong area?

If I understand protocols correctly it essentially determines a blue-print for classes to follow and as far as I have looked I cannot find where the function does not follow the blue-print that the protocol sets.

Protocol:

```
protocol VendingMachineType {
    var selection: [VendingSelection] { get }
    var inventory: [VendingSelection: ItemType] { get set }
    var amountDeposited: Double { get set }

    init(inventory: [VendingSelection: ItemType])
    func vend(selection: VendingSelection, quantity: Double) throws
    func deposit(amount: Double)
    func itemForCurrentSelection(selection: VendingSelection) -> ItemType?
}
```

Class:

```
class VendingMachine: VendingMachineType {
    let selection: [VendingSelection] = [.Soda, .DietSoda, .Chips, .Cookie, .Sandwich, .Wrap, .CandyBar, .PopTart, .Water, .FruitJuice, .SportsDrink, .Gum]

    var inventory: [VendingSelection: ItemType]
    var amountDesposited: Double = 10.0

    required init(inventory: [VendingSelection : ItemType]) {
        self.inventory = inventory
    }

    func vend(selection: VendingSelection, quantity: Double) throws {
        guard var item = inventory[selection] else {
            throw VendingMachineError.InvalidSelection
        }

        guard item.quantity > 0 else {
            throw VendingMachineError.OutOfStock
        }
        //at this point we have an item and a quantity implement a cancel button as homework here. 

        //time to reduce quantity by amount purchased

        item.quantity -= quantity
        inventory.updateValue(item, forKey: selection)


        //here we are checking to see if we have enough money and throwing an error if they do not
        let totalPrice = item.price * quantity
        if amountDesposited >= totalPrice {
            amountDesposited -= totalPrice
        } else {
            let amountRequired = totalPrice - amountDesposited
            throw VendingMachineError.InsufficientFunds(required: amountRequired)
        }
    }

    func itemForCurrentSelection(selection: VendingSelection) -> ItemType? {
        return inventory[selection]
    }

    func deposit(amount: Double) {
        amountDesposited += amount
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers in the correct direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with details about the error.

Comment: I misspelled the word "Deposit" as "Desposit" when I created the variable. You can see this in the protocol if you look at the third variable. After correcting this mistake the build has succeeded. Thank you everyone for your help, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your code into IBM Sandbox, and had to make a few simplifications since you have not pasted all of the code. Nevertheless, I got the same first error. The second error is what explains the issue:

```
protocol requires property 'amountDeposited' with type 'Double'
```

You have misspelled the property in your class definition.

Comment: That's embarrassing, I spelled "Deposit" as "Desposit" when I created the variable. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `VendingMachine`'s `amountDeposited` is a stored property. But protocol can declare computed properties only.